# How I can get value from class extends ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, future, flutter-provider

How I can get value from class extends ChangeNotifier
when I use `User user = Provider.of<UserController>(context, listen: false).user; => user null`?

```
class UserController extends ChangeNotifier {
   User _user;
   User get user => _user;

   Future<void> getUser() async {
      String token = await AppValue.getToken();
      Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://20.89.111.129/api/user/getProfileUser');
      Map<String, String> headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'};
      try {
          final response = await http.get(
              uri,
              headers: headers,
      );
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      User newUser = new User(
          address: (data['address'] == null) ? '' : data['address'],
          birthday: (data['birthday'] == null) ? '' : data['birthday'],
           email: (data['email'] == null) ? '' : data['email'],
           fullName: (data['fullName'] == null) ? '' : data['fullName'],
       );
     _user = newUser; // _user is not null
     notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
  log('ST WRONG!');
  throw (error);
}
}
}
// When I use User user = Provider.of<UserController>(context, listen: false).user; => user null
```

Comment: Please post the code here as plain text (formatted as code), not a link of an external image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to tell the provider the exact class you want to act on,

```
//so instead of this;
User user = Provider.of(context, listen: false).user;

// do this
User user = Provider.of< UserController>(context, listen: false).user;
```

Comment: I followed it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you call the getUser method before trying to access _user?

Comment: Yes, i called it
UserController().getUser();

Comment: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    UserController().getUser();
                    User user = UserController().user;
                    if (user == null)
                      log('User null !');
                    else
                      log('Name user : ${user.fullName}');
                  },
                  child: Text('GET PROFILE'),
                )

Comment: You can't do it this way. You have to call the function via provider like this:

`
ElevatedButton( 
     onPressed: () {
         await Provider.of< UserController>(context, listen: false).getUser(); 
        User user =  Provider.of< UserController>(context, listen: false).user;
        if (user == null){ 
        log('User null !');
        } else{
          log('Name user : ${user.fullName}'); 
        },
    }, 
   child: Text('GET PROFILE'), )
`

Comment: Hmm I tried, but have error
'The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.'

Comment: it only works when i put it in a function with async

Comment: Lol. My bad. The await only works in async function, so you have to specify the function as async.

 ElevatedButton( onPressed: () async { await Provider.of< UserController>(context, listen: false).getUser(); User user = Provider.of< UserController>(context, listen: false).user; if (user == null){ log('User null !'); } else{ log('Name user : ${user.fullName}'); }, }, child: Text('GET PROFILE'), )

Comment: You need to go see more tutorials and resources on State Management with Provider

Comment: I think so, Thank you for helping me :))

Comment: It is my pleasure.